# Can we track people who has installed by mobile app?

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, mobile-app-tracker

I have a sensor based mobile app and I want to send people to a particular shop and track who are all went to the shop and bought a product, by running a facebook app install campaign. Can I track the same? Is it possible? Kindly let me know it.. 
Thanks

Comment: It seems like violating privacy !! And this question is likely to get closed/downvoted. I suggest to try something from your end and come for help.

Comment: How this can be violating privacy? It's just a question I need a answer, I didn't even mentioned my app name, shop name or any web links. Then how is it violating privacy? Please explain me the reason.

Comment: I meant the kind of App being developed. Usually questions with code will get responses. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.